# How to build OSXFUSE.framework in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, macfuse, osxfuse

I already installed OSXFUSE from https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse but i don't know how to build OSXFUSE.framework to include it in the application. I also download the sample source from OSXFuse but it cannot build and show the error:

```
  ~/swift-drive-master/SwiftDrive/FileSystem.h:2:9: 'OSXFUSE/OSXFUSE.h' file not found
```

Please give me some advise. Thanks.

Comment: ..did you follow the **Build Instructions**?

Comment: Yes, already did as instruction

Comment: Did you include the framework installed at /Libraries as a reference to your project? I only managed to compile the project using the downloaded one from github

Answer (score 0):

1. open the project
2. go to add framework
3. choose add others
4. go to volume/library/frameworks/OSXFUSE.framework click open button.
5. done.

now OSXFUSE.framework  is imported to your xcode project